# Synthetic Mass...?

Tags: gravity

If I take a sphere (Very dense- say Uranium or other heavy element...), and magnetically set this sphere into motion at a very high rate of speed, Can I get this object to generate a artifical gravity field strong enough to grab hold of anything? This object will be suspended and not in contact with any other object while spinning.

I am thinking there might be another alternative to artifical gravity in a space station other than centerfugal force.

Comment: To give a real short answer: No

Answer (score 0):

You can, in theory, explore this scenario with the [Kerr metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric), which will model the spacetime outside your spherical mass.

However, the Kerr metric's main difference from the Schwarzschild metric on test particles is on their motions normal to the radius; these effects are much more pronounced than any effect on the motions in the radial direction, the Lense-Thirring effect (frame dragging) being the most notable. So you won't get a significant augmentation of attraction simply by spinning the sphere.

Moreover, by inspection of the metric, *any* effect is negligible unless the sphere's angular momentum $J$ is big enough that $\alpha = J/(M\,c)$ is comparable to the radial co-ordinate. We can approximate the angular momentum by its nonrelativistic expression $\frac{2}{3} M r_0^2 \omega$, where $M$ is the sphere's mass (you'd use a thin spherical shell rather than a solid sphere to augment the effect as much as you can) and $r_0$ its velocity.

If you're standing a distance $r$ meters from a sphere of radius $r_0$, then this means that:

$$\frac{2}{3} \frac{r_0^2\,\omega}{r\,c}\sim 1$$

for significant effect. Let's assume we can get the quantity to be 0.01 and that $r=r_0$ to measure the maximum effect when you're standing right next to the sphere. Even if the sphere is of 10 meter radius this implies the stupendous angular velocity of $0.01 \times \frac{3\,c}{2\,r} = 4.5\times 10^7$ radians per second.

So no earthly material is going to withstand the rotation needed to generate significant effects, which won't be what you need anyway.